# jQuery length property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with some images from the Flickr API using jQuery, and looping through the result set.

This works:

```
$.getJSON(apiCall, function(data) {
    //LOOP THROUGH DATA
    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, photo) {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

but when I added a check to make sure that the `photos` object was populated, the length property is undefined.

```
$.getJSON(apiCall, function(data) {

    console.log(data.photos.length); // returns undefined

    if(data.photos.length >= 1){
        //LOOP THROUGH DATA
        $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, photo) {
            // do stuff
        });
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

What is the proper way to determine whether the `photos` object is populated?

EDIT: sample of json data returned:

```
{"photos":{"page":1, "pages":100172, "perpage":50, "total":"5008581", "photo":[{"id":"8077408556", "owner":"75972124@N08", "secret":"ede5a49ab5", "server":"8323", "farm":9, "title":"zara 2", "ispublic":1, "isfriend":0, "isfamily":0}. . .
```

Yes, it is possible to simply test if `photos.total >= 1` but I'm curious about the length property.

Comment: Can you show a sample of json data.. It is difficult to say without knowing the structure of your json

Comment: @Sushanth--adding sample of json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.getJSON(apiCall, function(data) {

    console.log(data.photos.photo.length); // returns undefined

    if(data.photos.photo.length >= 1){
        //LOOP THROUGH DATA
        $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, photo) {
            // do stuff
        });
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

To get the length, you need to use `data.photos.photo`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `data.photos` is an object, rather than an array. Objects do not have a `length` property unless you specify one.

The way to test the number of elements in an object is with `Object.keys`. This makes an array with all the keys in the object as its elements. The length of this array is therefore the number of keys in the object.

```
if (Object.keys(data.photos).length >= 1) {
```

Note that the `Object.keys` function was introduced in ECMA5, and is not available in many browsers. The MDN website includes [code that adds it to older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Just use the length property to get the length of the photo property:

```
data["photos"]["photo"].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for null rather then length for an `object` . this is not an array to check for length

Instead of

```
if(data.photos.length >= 1){
```

Try

```
if(data.photos != null){
```

//

```
$.getJSON(apiCall, function(data) {

    //console.log(data.photos.length); // returns undefined

    if(data.photos != null){  // OR if(data.photos)
        //LOOP THROUGH DATA
        $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, photo) {
            // do stuff
        });
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through `data.photos.photo` which is an array and has a length property, which should be accessed via `data.photos.photo.length`.

If you simply want to check that `data.photos` has something on its `photo` property before iterating, you could use `if (data.photos.photo)`.